# param is missing or the value is empty: But parameter IS there with a value

Tags: ruby-on-rails

FYI, VERY new to Rails

param is missing or the value is empty: roster_id
Extracted source (around line #83):
81
82
83
84
85

```
  #  end
  def locker_params
    params.require(:roster_id).permit(:id,  :next_due, :notes, :key_num, :lockernum, :location, :row, :size, :memberID)
  end
end
```

Application Trace | Framework Trace | Full Trace
app/controllers/lockers_controller.rb:83:in `locker_params'
app/controllers/lockers_controller.rb:52:in`block in update'
app/controllers/lockers_controller.rb:51:in `update'
Request
Parameters:

```
{"utf8"=>"✓",
 "_method"=>"patch",
 "authenticity_token"=>"uq6+5NchGu0or3JfIquY99goeg8uOQ5B2ttMTQ2O6mgE/aeoNyUT7Le+i+n/Ug5a44rwQkJ/ZhecTlJgnZzhtQ==",
 "locker"=>{"roster_id"=>"199", "location"=>"FrontL    "},
 "commit"=>"Update Locker",
 "id"=>"573"}
```

As you can see in the request, the parameter roster_id is in the request and does have a value.

The form uses an array built from the rosters table

```
    <div class="actions">
  <%= form.collection_select(:roster_id,@rosters.all, :id, :formatted_name)  %>
  Location <%= form.text_field :location %>
    <%= form.submit %>
  </div>
```

What am I missing.  If I remove the .require and add roster_id into the permit, the form doesn't error out, but the table doesn't update.

Comment: `params.require(:locker).permit(:roster_id, :id,  :next_due, :notes, :key_num, :lockernum, :location, :row, :size, :memberID)`

Comment: Also you'll benefit from [the rails tutorial](https://www.railstutorial.org/)

Answer (score 2):

I think you're trying to require the wrong parameter so your `locker_params` method is returning empty. Try:

`params.require(:locker).permit(:roster_id, :location...)`

Comment: It's not returning empty params, it's raising an exception